# jquery Не забирает значения двух блоков

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не знаю как исправить.
Необходимо,чтобы при клике на один из блоков в массив(переменную) записывалось значение блока, а при клике на второй блок значение записывалось в следующий элемент массива(другую переменную).Больше двух одновременно нажатых кнопок быть не должно.Значения двух блоков должны выводиться в alert сразу после выделения второго блока черной рамкой. Помогите, кто знает.

```js
var act_cout=0;
var i=0;
var  val= new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){


 $('.card').on("click",function(){
   $(this).addClass("active");
   
   val[i]=$(this).parent(".pole").find('div.active').text();
   
   
  
  
   
   i++;
   if ( i>2) {
    alert(val[0]+val[1]);
    $('.active').removeClass("active"); 

  }
  });
 
  

 });
```

```css
.pole {
  display: flex;
}
.active {
  border: 4px solid black;
}
.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="piraStyle.css">
 <title>piramid</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="pole">
  <div class="card">8</div>
  <div class="card">5</div>
  <div class="card">4</div>
  <div class="card">9</div>
  <div class="card">5</div>
  <div class="card">8</div>

 </div>
 
 <script src="code.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let sum = 0;
let val= new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){


 $('.card').on("click",function(){
   $(this).addClass("active");
   
   
   val.push($(this).text());
  
   
   if ( val.length === 2) {
    val.forEach(function(e){
          sum = sum + parseInt(e);
        });
        alert(sum);
        sum = 0;
    $('.active').removeClass("active"); 
        val = new Array();

  }
  });
 
  

 });
```

```css
.pole {
  display: flex;
}
.active {
  border: 4px solid black;
}
.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="piraStyle.css">
 <title>piramid</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="pole">
  <div class="card">8</div>
  <div class="card">5</div>
  <div class="card">4</div>
  <div class="card">9</div>
  <div class="card">5</div>
  <div class="card">8</div>

 </div>
 
 <script src="code.js"></script>
</body>
```